# Getting text from specific richtextbox line

Tags: c#, richtextbox, readline

I am still new to using forms and every thing that comes with it i am wanting to get all of the text from the first line in a richtextbox and nothing else with it. I have been looking into this for about 3 hours now and haven't gotten any closer to figuring it out if any one could help would be great.

Comment: Are you using any specific plugging? have you tried `.innerText`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
string firstLine = RichTextBox.Lines[0];
```

You could use the same logic to get any of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to get the first line:

```
var line = richTextBox1.Lines[0];
```

or using LINQ:

```
var line = richTextBox1.Lines.FirstOrDefault();
```

You can read more about `RichTextBox` [here](http://visualcsharptutorials.com/windows-forms/richtextbox-control).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var firstLine = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a specific line you need by checking for a containing value.

```
    public static string GetLine(RichTextBox richTb, string myValue)
    {
        string[] lines = richTb.Lines;
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains(myValue))
            {
                return line;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Or you can get something else like a name doing this:

```
    public static string GetSpecificValue(RichTextBox richTb, string myValue)
    {
        string[] lines = richTb.Lines;
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains(myValue))
            {
                return line.Split(':')[1].TrimStart();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In this case, this is the use of it:

```
    private void GetName()
    {
        /* Assuming there is a line that reads
         * Name: John Doe, then the returned value
         * would be John Doe */

        txtName.Text = GetSpecificValue(richTextBox, "Name");
    }
```